Get all event hashes for ABI
I have a smart contract ABI. What's the easiest way to compute the keccak256 hashes for the events in the contract?

To automate computing the keccak256 hashes for all events in a smart contract ABI, you can loop through the ABI, extract event definitions, generate their signatures, and compute the keccak256 hash for each one.
Here's the minimal script to achieve the same using ethers.js:
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

// Example ABI (Replace this with your actual contract ABI)
const abi = [
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" },
            { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" },
            { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" },
            { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" },
            { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    }
];

// Function to compute Keccak256 hashes for all events in the ABI
function computeEventHashes(abi) {
    abi.forEach(item => {
        if (item.type === 'event') {
            // Construct event signature: EventName(type1, type2, ...)
            const eventSignature = `${item.name}(${item.inputs.map(input => input.type).join(',')})`;

            // Compute Keccak256 hash
            const eventHash = ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(eventSignature));

            // Output the event signature and its hash
            console.log(`Event Signature: ${eventSignature}`);
            console.log(`Event Hash: ${eventHash}\n`);
        }
    });
}

// Call the function with the ABI
computeEventHashes(abi);

OUTPUT:

